# Comparing a string from a list to a datagridview column value

Tags: c#

I have a `List<string>` with a list of SKU's that need to be removed from a `DataGridView` column

```
foreach (DataRow row in AlreadyHarmedDataTable.Rows)
{
    alreadyHarmedList.Add(row[0].ToString());
}

foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dgvData.Rows)
{
    foreach (string sku in alreadyHarmedList)
    {
        if (sku == dgvData.Rows[0].ToString())
        {
            dgvData.Rows.Remove(row);
        }
    }
}
```

There are no skus being removed.

The problem currently is that

```
dgvData.Rows[0].ToString()
```

Is not returning a string whats in that row for the first column. It gives me the Object name in the string

How can I loop through my `DataGridView` and my List at the same time, to delete all rows where the first column = a string in the `List<>`

Edit:

I tried

```
if (sku == row.Cells[0].Value.ToString())
```

and I get the following exception

```
System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'
```

I tried a solution from the irrelevant question that supposedly this is a duplicate of...

```
if(sku == row.Cells[dgvData.Columns["sku"].Index].Value.ToString())
```

Comment: @Igor where in my question did I ask how to set the cell value of a datagrid cell?

Comment: If you know how to assign the cell a value you then you could apply that same logic to read the value of a cell.

Comment: Hence where my issue is and why im asking a question.

Comment: `if(sku == row.Cells["sku"].Value)`  (*as per the linked duplicate*)

Comment: How come when I used the index of the column it was not working?

Comment: It does work but if you have `null` as the value in the cell then calling `ToString()` on it will throw an `NullReferenceException`. The easiest way to do a case sensitive comparison is what I have in the comments or you have to add a null check.